# php mailer does not work when extension is removed on htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have .htaccess that removes .php and .html extensions, however, my php mailer stops working If I understand correctly because it's trying to post to email.php.

Is there a work around that I can try or  can someone advise on how I can fix this ?

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

email.php

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';


if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
    $subject = htmlentities($_POST['subject']);
    $message = htmlentities($_POST['message']);

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('email@email');
    $mail->Subject = ("$email ($subject)");
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->send();

    header("Location: ./response.html");
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<form class="center_absolute display_grid row_gap_1_rem" action="email.php" method="post">
   
      <div class="primary-input-content-container">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="primary-input background_color_white color_black font_size_medium" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
      <div class="primary-input-content-container">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="primary-input background_color_white color_black font_size_medium" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="primary-input-content-container">
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="primary-input background_color_white color_black font_size_medium" placeholder="Subject" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
    
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
     
    <button type="submit" name="send">
      Send 
    </button>
  </form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It stops working, because you are making an external redirect - which the browser will follow up using a GET request, so you lose all your POST data. `action="email.php"` - this should only point to `email`, the `.php` will be added via the internal rewrite you have implemented.

Comment: And you should probably exempt POST requests from your .php-to-suffix-less redirect to begin with, to avoid getting the same problem again if you forget to modify another form action accordingly, or perhaps have AJAX POST requests that otherwise might suffer the same fate.